# Is exist a simple way to get element to which attribute is applied (without link to it as a parameter)?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I've defined the `delegate` and `Attribute`:

```
delegate void Operation();
/// <summary>
/// Methods are marked by this attribute, will be added into menu as the 
/// menu items.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false,
    Inherited = true)]
internal class CommandAttribute : Attribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attribute constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="msgId">ID of the localized string of the menu item.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="classType">The type which has the target method.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="methodName">The name of the method which will be 
    /// called when menu item selected.</param>
    public CommandAttribute(String msgId, Type classType,
        String methodName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(msgId))
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid value of the " + nameof(msgId));
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(methodName))
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid value of the " + nameof(methodName));
        }

        if (null == classType)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(classType));
        }
        Operation = null;
        MessageId = msgId;
        ClassType = classType;
        MethodName = methodName;
        MethodInfo mi = classType.GetMethod(methodName);
        if (null != mi)
        {
            Operation = (Operation)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Operation),
            classType.GetMethod(methodName));
        }
    }

    public String MessageId { get; }

    public string MethodName { get; }

    public Operation Operation { get; }

    Type ClassType { get; }
}
```

Now I use my attibute:

```
class Commands
{
    [Command("SetSources", typeof(Commands), "SetSources")]
    public static void SetSources()
    {
        // here is some code...
    }
}
```

And I build my menu:

```
foreach (var s in typeof(Commands).GetMethods())
{
    CommandAttribute att = s.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CommandAttribute))
        .Cast<CommandAttribute>().FirstOrDefault() as CommandAttribute;
    if (null != att && null != att.Operation)
    {
        AddMenuItem(att);
    }
}
```

But I don't like existence of the second and third parameter in the constructor of attribute...

Whether it is possible in an attribute code somehow differently to receive the link to an element to which this attibute is applied?

Comment: You could move the code to create the operation out of the attribute and extend the `AddMenuItem` method to also receive the method as a parameter besides the attribute. This way, the creation of the delegate is IMHO placed at a more appropriate location because I suspect you need the operation right when you create the menu item.

Comment: You foreaches all methods. The only way to get an attribute for a method is to have its `MethodInfo`. If you have it, you know all you want. `MethodInfo.Name` contains the method name and `MethodInfo.DeclaringType` contains the type where this method is declared. What else do you need? MethodInfo together with your attribute contains all information and you don't need these two ctor-args. There is no link from attribute to what it is applied.

Comment: Thank you, @Markus. <br/> > This way, the creation of the delegate is IMHO placed at a more appropriate location because I suspect you need the operation right when you create the menu item. <br/> I don't  understand about the *operation right*. Can you explain this?

Comment: Thank you, @Vera rind. I will try to rewrite my code via the `MethodInfo`.

Comment: @AndreyBushman by "you need the operation right when..." I meant "you need the operation _at the point in time_ when...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the `operation` delegate in the constructor of the attribute, I'd propose to use the attribute only as a marker and move the creation of the delegate to the `AddMenuItem` method:

```
void AddMenuItem(CommandAttribute att, MethodInfo method)
{
    // ...
    // Create and use operation delegate in this method
    var operation = (Operation)Delegate.CreateDelegate(method.DeclaringType,
        method);
    // ...
}
```

Besides reducing the probability of an error in the constructor of the attribute, you already have all necessary information when collecting the commands in the `foreach` loop so you do not have to use reflection to get them again:

```
foreach (var s in typeof(Commands).GetMethods())
{
    CommandAttribute att = s.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CommandAttribute))
        .Cast<CommandAttribute>().FirstOrDefault() as CommandAttribute;
    if (null != att && null != att.Operation)
    {
        AddMenuItem(att, s);
    }
}
```